# How can I calculate a percentage of a preceding number in a SQL table?

Tags: amazon-redshift, periscope

I'm creating a retention cohort which shows the retention of my user base on our app, but I only know how to calculate the results in a count version, however, I really want the results to be percentages of the total cohort starting group (i.e. in month zero we had 1000 active users on the platform but in month 2 only 500 of those users were still active so the retention percentage for month 2 would be 50%, in month 3 only 300 were still active so retention = 30%).

Code i've written that calculates the count for each month below:

```
select count(distinct u.id), count(t.id), [u.created:month] as ucm, (datediff(month,[u.created:month],[t.createdon:month])) as cohort
from [user_cache as u]
right join [transaction_cache as t] on t.owner = u.id
and t.status = 'successful' and t.type = 'savings'
where [u.created:year] > ['2017-01-01':date:year]
group by ucm, cohort
order by ucm asc
```

Thank you

Comment: It's querying data that is cached within Periscope, so the code has to be redshift compatible. I'm very new to SQL, I thought it was tsql but I likely made a mistake there.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you query is invalid standard SQL). [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I believe i'm using postgreSQL after doing some research. Our database runs through AWS redshift.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. Change the subquery in line 4 to select the correct initial cohort. If running this over multiple years, you will need to account for year and month in the GROUP BY, but the logic remains the same.

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(MONTH,t.createdon) month
    , COUNT(*) activeCohortNumber
    , COUNT(*)*100.00 / 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.transaction_cache WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,createdon) = 1) 
     AS activeCohortPercent
FROM user_cache AS u
RIGHT JOIN transaction_cache AS t ON t.owner = u.id
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH,t.createdon)
```